# Ready for sale iOS app cannot able to find in appstore

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I uploaded an iOS app to appstore and now the app got released and the release date is showing as 3 August 2012 and yesterday the status (ready for sale) changed. In the uploading process we had specified some places like France, Luxembourg, Switzerland, Belgium in "Select the App Stores where your app will be sold" section.

We tried to get the app in the appstore (US) but we are getting a message as the app is not currently available in US appstore, we are now in India and also we tried to view the app by clicking the view in appstore link in the iTunes connect app page but the above given message is being shown (the app is not currently available in US appstore).

Is this a problem with the selected place for appstore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the uploading process we had specified some places like France, Luxembourg, Switzerland, Belgium in "Select the App Stores where your app will be sold" section.

Did those "some places" include the US? If not, I can't imagine why you'd expect the app to be available in the US app store.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We haven't included US in the sold place, because our client mentioned us to put the above given places(france,Luxembourg,Switzerland,Belgium) now we are in India we cannot find the app in appstore ,is this issue due to the unselection of place US?

Comment: Then the application will not be available for sale in the US. Simple as that. If you wanted it to be available in the US, you should have said so!

Comment: But we need to view the app from India for checking

Comment: Can we Edit the selected country option with out a review?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set the Availability date prior to current date. Check in Your App --> Rights & Pricing -> Availability date.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your app is not set as being available to be sold in the US App Store so you will not be able to find your app listed in the US App Store there.

To view the app, you will need an Apple ID that is set up for one of the countries in which the app is available e.g. France.

Log into iTunes/App Store using that Apple ID and you will be able to search the apps for that country.

If you are setting up a new Apple ID just for testing, then I recommend you follow the steps for setting up an Apple ID without a credit card (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534). Otherwise, you're going to have the extra hassle of having to enter credit card details for a credit card before you'll be able to access the App Store/iTunes Store.

Note: it does take time (i.e. numerous hours) for an app to appear in the app store once you've released it.